# Cant figure out how to access my file in another folder

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, directory

Basically i have my file index.php its located somewhere in the middle and my image folder located 3 folders down and i want to access it the code i used looks like this

```
$uri = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

<img src = "'$uri.'/images/dogs/circle/dog1.jpg">
```

this is the link that forms after my code

```
www.dog.com/folder1/folder2/index.php/images/dogs/circle/dog1.jpg
```

i need the index.php removed but i need the rest of it, how would i go about removing it.

Comment: why don't you just use `<img src="images/dogs/circle/dog1.jpg">` ?

Comment: Seems overly complex indeed. Good suggestion using relative path instead! Also, if you're dead set on doing it in PHP, there are easier ways..

Comment: i tried it that way originally but it wouldn't work, it works on my local server that way but when i put it online it fails and gives me broken links

Comment: You can just hardcode it: `<img src="/folder1/folder2/images/dogs/circle/dog1.jpg">`

Answer (score 2):

ok so i found a way to make this work I doubt it elegant but basically what i did was made a variable uri and used it to get the begining

```
$uri = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
<img src= "'.$uri.'/images/travel.square/dog1.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply achieved with the `str_replace()` function which will search a given string and replace matched cases.

Below we replace the string `index.php/` with nothing, theoretically removing it from the original string. I chose to remove the trailing slash as well because if you don't im almost 100 % positive you will end up with `www.dog.com/folder1/folder2//images/...`

```
$uri = str_replace('index.php/','',"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

And then you simply echo out html code you want.

```
echo '<img src = "'.$uri.'/images/dogs/circle/dog1.jpg">';
```

Comment: I havnt been on this site enough to up or down vote yet

Comment: well in any case you try this out?

Comment: i am about to now also when i try it with the relative path as the person who commented on my question said it gives me http://www.dog.com/images/dogs/circle/dog1.jpg its missing folder1 and folder 2 in the link

Comment: Are you sure this works? You're swapping out `index.php/` from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - I don't think the trailing slash is needed

Comment: FYI someone most likely downvoted this because it is code with no context  / explanation / discussion.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this

```
$uri = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$split=explode("/",$uri);
array_pop($split);
$uri=implode("/",$split);



<img src = "'$uri.'/images/dogs/circle/dog1.jpg">
```